# Getting Multiple Functions to Run Together Successfully

Tags: google-apps-script

I'm new to Google Apps Script and coding in general. I have a pretty specific goal I am trying to accomplish: that is to have a pop-up generated when a checkbox is selected, displaying a range of information from another sheet. I have written a script to help me accomplish this. The myFunction part of the script works if I use it alone with the built-in Google trigger for any cell edits. However, I'm trying to make it so it runs automatically when a box is checked specifically from one column (column C, starting with Row 4) with the onEdit function. It's taken me a long time to even make it this far, what am I missing to make it run properly? Any help is appreciated!

```
function Player_Detail(){
  onEdit(e);
  myfunction();
}

function onEdit(e) { 
    
  const row = e.range.getRow();
  const col = e.range.getColumn();
  const as = e.source.getActiveSheet();
  
  if(as.getName() == 'Top Projected Prospects'&& row>3 && col==3);
  }

function myfunction(){
  const ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
  const html = HtmlService.createHtmlOutput('<iframe width="670" height="685" src="https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1zdHfv8nMQSQ1WsnZKdCtvs7BXJZftF95Ml6f3rhRYmo/edit#gid=1458157110"></iframe>');
  html.setWidth(710);
  html.setHeight(710);

  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();

  spreadsheet.getCurrentCell().setValue('FALSE');

  var range_to_copy = spreadsheet.getCurrentCell().offset(0, -2);
  var range_to_paste = spreadsheet.getSheetByName('Player Detail').getRange(2, 3, 1, 1);

  range_to_copy.copyTo(range_to_paste, {contentsOnly: true});

  ui.showModalDialog(html, "Player Detail");

  //  ui.showModelessDialog(html, "Player Detail");
  //  ui.showModalDialog(html, "Player Detail");
}
```

Okay, I've made some edits. Now the script appears to behave as expected, when I check a box (in column C, beginning row 4) it copies my ID and pastes it to the other sheet as it's supposed to. However now the modal dialog box is not appearing with that sheet's range of info.  After testing, this appears to be the only thing that's not working and once I get it ironed out, my script should be complete! Here is the current script:

```
 function onEdit(e) { 
        
      const range = e.range;
        if (range.getRow() > 3 &&
        range.getColumn() === 3) {
    
      var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
    
      spreadsheet.getCurrentCell().setValue('FALSE');
    
      var range_to_copy = spreadsheet.getCurrentCell().offset(0, -2);
      var range_to_paste = spreadsheet.getSheetByName('Player Detail').getRange(2, 3, 1, 1);
    
      range_to_copy.copyTo(range_to_paste, {contentsOnly: true});
    
      const ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
      const html = HtmlService.createHtmlOutput('<iframe width="670" height="685" src="https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1zdHfv8nMQSQ1WsnZKdCtvs7BXJZftF95Ml6f3rhRYmo/edit#gid=1458157110"></iframe>');
      html.setWidth(710);
      html.setHeight(710);
    
      ui.showModalDialog(html, "Player Detail");
    
      //  ui.showModelessDialog(html, "Player Detail");
      //  ui.showModalDialog(html, "Player Detail");
      }
    }
```

Comment: You cannot run onEdit(e) from Player_Detail like that unless you supply the event object

Comment: Can you expand on that some? I'm not sure what it means to supply the event object.

Comment: Would it make more sense if I combined the two functions into one? I struggled with getting that to work and this was my workaround.

Comment: an onEdit(e) function is trigger by an onEdit simple trigger which supplies an event object to the trigger function that provides information range, value, oldvalue, user and more. Yeah I would combine the two functions into one.  And use the event object as much as possible since you don't have to run any functions to get that data.  It may be a challange at first but that's how you get better at it.

Comment: Thank you. I combined them into one function and now everything is working as expected when I check a box, except for some reason the ModalDialog popup is not triggering. Editing does not appear to be limited to the column I want it to be either. Still some learning to do it seems.

Comment: If share what you have now, maybe we can help.  Just add it to your question at the bottom

Comment: @Cooper - thank you for all of your help! I pasted the new script above. Basically the ModalDialog prompt is no longer popping up, which is the only thing that does not seem to be working. Any ideas on what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this is basically the same thing on less function calls although may be you don't care since you have a dialog launched in there.  Did you know that functions called by simple triggers must finish within 30 seconds?

```
function onEdit(e) {
  const sh = e.range.getSheet();
  if (sh.getName() == "Your Sheet Name" && e.range.rowStart > 3 && e.range.columnStart == 3) {
    e.range.setValue('FALSE');
    var range_to_copy = e.range.offset(0, -2);
    var range_to_paste = e.source.getSheetByName('Player Detail').getRange(2, 3);
    range_to_copy.copyTo(range_to_paste, { contentsOnly: true });
    const ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
    const html = HtmlService.createHtmlOutput('<iframe width="670" height="685" src="https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1zdHfv8nMQSQ1WsnZKdCtvs7BXJZftF95Ml6f3rhRYmo/edit#gid=1458157110"></iframe>');
    html.setWidth(710);
    html.setHeight(710);
    ui.showModalDialog(html, "Player Detail");
  }
}
```

Comment: I did read that somewhere - do you think that's my issue? Your concise script is awesome, thanks for sharing! I'm still having the same issue where the modaldialog popup screen is not launching though! It strikes me as odd because the popup was launching just fine before I added the onedit function to the script.

Comment: It is unusual to put a dialog into a function that is so short lived.  I don't think there is any restrictions if you choose to use an installable trigger.  If you do please change the name of the function to anything but onEdit() otherwise you will return wondering why your function is getting triggered twice.

Comment: Ohhhh, I think I finally understand! It sounds like the dialog is closing because the function is ending, is that right?

Comment: I would be guessing but that is a possibility

Comment: Thank you very much! Knowing that at least let's me know how I need to proceed from here!